# Iterator from both ends of a Vector

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a vector of IntRect: vector.

How can I iterate from both ends of the list and stop the iterator when the iterator intersects?

```
vector<IntRect>::iterator itr = myVector.begin();
  vector<IntRect>::reverse_iterator revItr.rbegin();

  for (; /*check itr and revItr does not intersect, and itr and revItr do not end */ ; ++itr, ++revItr) {
    IntRect r1 = *itr;
    IntRect r2 = *revItr;

    // do something with r1 and r2

  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: @Johannes  Closing two of your own answers must be some sort of record. Maybe you should ask Jeff to create a new badge for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(!myVector.empty()) {
    for(vector<IntRect>::iterator forwards = myVector.begin(), 
                                  backwards = myVector.end()-1;
        forwards < backwards;
        ++forwards, --backwards) {

            // do stuff
    }
}
```

I think you need to check `empty()` with that implementation - suspect that `end()-1` isn't defined if the vector is empty. I haven't used it before, but Dinkumware STL at least has operator < defined for vector iterators and it appears to do something sensible.

Also note that you need to check <, not just equality - that takes care of the (common) case where your vector has an even number of entries and the two iterators would step past one another.

Comment: Yep, so does end()-1. Fortunately we know it's a vector :)

Comment: `begin()-1` is undefined, and therefore `end()-1` isn't defined for an empty vector either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`base`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/reverse_iterator/base/) function on the reverse iterator and compare the result with your forward iterator.

Remember that if you're moving both iterators, they will never be equal if the sequence has odd number of elements. You have to check the equality twice in each iteration.

Comment: Be careful with `base` -- it doesn't quite do what a lot of people think it does!

(Namely, `base` does not point to the same element as the reverse iterator.)

Comment: Indeed, there would be no base for `rend()` otherwise.

Comment: agreed with your comments on my answer: I was over-generalizing. We should only care about random access iterators here, and provide a more optimized version for lists if we really need. Or we should really go a bit more lowlevel and do the two checks like you mention.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers that I've seen account for the two iterators "passing in the night."

```
vector<IntRect>::iterator forward = myVector.begin(), backward = myVector.end();

while (forward != backward)
{
    ++forward;

    // at this point they could be equal
    if (forward == backward)
        break;

    --backward;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iterators point to the same thing if `&(*itr) == &(*revItr)`

Assuming nobody has done something stupid and overloaded `operator&` on IntRect.

Comment: But take care of the special case where there are no elements in the sequence :)

Comment: Err... isn't `&(*iter) == &(*revItr)` the same as `itr == revItr`?

Comment: that doesn't compare iterators; it compares addresses (actual raw pointers).

Comment: No, I mean there's no `operator==` defined for those two types AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the second (reverse) iterator with a regular one and have that initialised to `--myVector.end()`. Instead of incrementing it, decrement it and compare the iterator values.

Comment: You can't initialize to `--myVector.end()` since `myVector.end()` is immutable.

Comment: You can however initialise to `myVector.end()` and then decrement it. Should've been clearer.